# Get the cell value (eg. A6) of the cell which triggered the macro

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to to get the cell value (eg. A6) of the cell which triggered the macro i have here:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A50")) Is Nothing Then
      Call first_module
    End If
End Sub
```

What I would like to know is, which row that triggered the marco and then copy the whole row to another Workbook. So if there is any change in A20, row 20 will be copied and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: target is the cell(s) that were changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Worksheet_Change` can be triggered by a change to multiple cells, so you need to account for that in your code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, cDest As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:A50")) 'Calculate intersect
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then                                  'any intersect cells?
        Set cDest = Workbooks("data.xlsx").Sheets("Data") _
             .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'next empty row...
        For Each c in rng.cells            'loop over all cells
            c.EntireRow.Copy cDest         'copy row to other workbook
            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next paste row
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll need to add a parameter to your copy method which accepts the Range to be copied.

If you're just starting in VBA then avoiding Call is a good practise - it's pretty much deprecated these days and is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot and I'll avoid using Call.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any further documentation on ''copyRow c.EntireRow''. Can you help with a link or something, where I can learn a bit more how it works and how to paste it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you already had some code (`first_module`) for the actual copy: I just put a "dummy" method name since you hadn't provided much detail around where the copied row should be pasted.  See my edits above

Answer (score 0):

To copy the entire row that the target cell is in (or cells are in):

```
Target.EntireRow.Copy
```